# Why is error shown during compiling my document?

Tags: equations, report, mathematics

I have written a document with equations in it. The equations are written with $ on both sides. But
there are certain errors displayed while compiling which I'm unable to rectify as I'm unable to understand the errors.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
            \title{\vspace{-1.5cm}}{\huge\textbf{3-field continuum model}}\\
        \end{center}
    \hrule
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    The model consists of the following parametres:

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Pressure,\hspace{0.5em}P\\
        \begin{eqnarray}
    $\frac{3}{2} \frac{\delta P}{\delta t}- \frac {\delta}{\delta x}[\chi_{neo}+\chi_{ano} 
     f_s(v_E^',S)]\frac{\delta P}{\delta x}=H(x)$
        \end{eqnarray}
        \item Density, \hspace{0.5em}n\\
    $ \frac{\delta n}{\delta t}-\frac{\delta}{\delta x}[D_{neo}+D_{ano} f_s(v_E^',S)]\frac{n} 
     {x}=S(x)$     
        \item Turbulence intensity,\hspace{0.5em}I
    \end{enumerate}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The code as given **now** compiles into the image given in @Mico 's answer with my MiKTeX-distribution. However, it was missing half a dozen packages, which I installed. So besides Latex-syntax: What kind of errors did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your code features a considerable variety of syntax errors. Among the most important ones are (i) the use of `$` to initiate (inline) math mode while already inside a display math mode and (ii) the use of `^'` instead of just `'` to generate "prime" symbols. Oh, please don't use `eqnarray` in a LaTeX document; `equation` does just well, or even better. And do get rid of code cruft, such as `\title{\vspace{-1.5cm}}`. (What on earth is that about?!)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % 'mathpazo' is very old
\usepackage[onehalfspacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\huge\textbf{3-field continuum model}
\end{center}
\hrule

\vspace*{0.5cm}
\noindent
The model consists of the following parameters:

\begin{enumerate}

\item Pressure, $P$
 \begin{equation}
 \frac{3}{2} \frac{\delta P}{\delta t} - \frac {\delta}{\delta x}
 \bigl[\chi_{\mathrm{neo}}+\chi_{\mathrm{ano}}\, f_s(v_E',S)\bigr]
 \frac{\delta P}{\delta x}=H(x)
 \end{equation}
    
\item Density, $n$
 \[
 \frac{\delta n}{\delta t} - \frac{\delta}{\delta x}
 \bigl[D_{\mathrm{neo}}+D_{\mathrm{ano}}\, f_s(v_E',S)\bigr]
 \frac{n}{x}=S(x)
 \]  
 
\item Turbulence intensity, $I$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```